# cp command for backup

Tags: command-line, backup, find, cp

I'm trying to copy (backup) a specific folder files (no directories and sub-directories files) to a second folder. I nested find command with backstick but it give me error for each file with file_name (copy).extension

```
cp -a -t /home/gianmarco/backup2 `find /home/gianmarco/backup1 -maxdepth 1 -type f`
cp: cannot stat '/home/gianmarco/backup1/helloWorld': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '(copy).txt': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/home/gianmarco/backup1/2nuovoFile': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '(copy).txt': No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` to run `cp` on those files:

```
find /home/gianmarco/backup1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp -at /home/gianmarco/backup2 {} +
```

This way, spaces and other special characters in the filenames won't be a problem. When you use command substitution without quoting, the shell will split the output on spaces, then perform wildcard expansion, etc. It's simpler to use `find` itself for this. Or see [How can I exclude all subdirectories but include files of a directory in rsync?](https://askubuntu.com/q/632091/158442)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works 100%!!! I've completely forget the -exec in find ....

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

```
find /path_to_source/ -depth -type f -exec cp -apt /path_to_target_directory/ {} \;
```

where the `-depth` option makes `find` traverse the file system in a depth-first order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **rsync**. In this exmaple I call syncronize all files & folders in **src** dir to **dst**, excluding `.sh` files, preserving permissions, ownership, timestamp:

`rsync -a --exclude '*.sh' /path/to/src /path/to/dst`

Also, you can add some additional parameters, it depends on your situation.

Answer (score -1):

`find /home/gianmarco/backup1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} /home/gianmarco/backup2`